# Iterating thorugh coordinates and inserting them in Folium map

Tags: python, typeerror

I have a CSV file and within it are postcodes (around 100) and want to transfrom them into latitude and longitude respectively into a list

```
import postcodes_io_api
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\example.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    postcodes=(row['Postcode'])

    api  = postcodes_io_api.Api(debug_http=True)

    data = api.get_postcode(postcodes)

    latitude = data['result']['latitude']
    longitude = data['result']['longitude']

    m=folium.Map(location=[57.2432, -2.4490])
```

However I can't manage to store them properly in a list and this error appears when I try to transform

```
import postcodes_io_api
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\example.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
postcodes=(row['Postcode'])

api  = postcodes_io_api.Api(debug_http=True)

data = api.get_postcode(postcodes)

latitude = list(data['result']['latitude'])
longitude = list(data['result']['longitude'])

m=folium.Map(location=[57.2432, -2.4490])

print(type(latitude))

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-d15850e92284> in <module>
     13     data = api.get_postcode(postcodes)
     14 
---> 15     latitude = list(data['result']['latitude'])
     16     longitude = list(data['result']['longitude'])
     17 

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

The `list()` function in python is a constructor. If you pass through an iterable (a string, a tuple, a set, or a dictionary for example) it will create a list from the items within the iterable.

This constructor can not receive a 'float', in this case the latitude and longitude results, because floats are not iterable.

Instead simply change the two lines to

```
latitude = [data['result']['latitude']]
longitude = [data['result']['longitude']]
```

although if you are going to be passing these through to the folium Map method, you may not need to put them in lists. you could simply store them as floats and then pass them through as

```
latitude = data['result']['latitude']
longitude = data['result']['longitude']
m = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude])
```